# Dagger Hilt - Fragment Binding getting Null?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

### Update

If I remove the `@Inject` annotation from `mPresenter` in the `SearchFragment` and just create the dependency at runtime, say in `onCreateView()` via

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    mPresenter = SearchPresenter(this)
    // ...
}
```

Then the bug just magically disappears, so it probably has something to do with Hilt.

### Original Post

I'm using Dagger-Hilt 2.38 in my app, which has an `Activity` and a `Fragment` in it, which in turn has an `EditText`. However, after `onTextChange()` event, I get:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
> mBinding has not been initialized
> at SearchFragment.onSearchResult(SearchFragment.kt:65)
> at SearchPresenter.search(SearchPresenter.kt:18)
> at SearchFragment$onCreateView$1.onTextChanged(SearchFragment.kt:36)
> at ...

Any help is much appreciated! Below is my setup:

#### MainActivity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mSearchFragment: SearchFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, mSearchFragment)
            .commit()
    }
    
}
```

#### Search Module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object SearchModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideView(): SearchContract.View {
        return SearchFragment()
    }

    @Provides
    fun providePresenter(view: SearchContract.View): SearchContract.Presenter {
        return SearchPresenter(view)
    }

}
```

#### SearchFragment

```
class SearchFragment @Inject constructor() : Fragment(), SearchContract.View {

    private lateinit var mBinding: FragmentSearchBinding

    @Inject
    lateinit var mPresenter: SearchContract.Presenter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        mBinding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        mBinding.edittextSearch.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                mPresenter.search(p0.toString().trim())
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        })

        mBinding.recyclerview.apply {
            adapter = SearchAdapter(mPresenter.getCompanies())
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@SearchFragment.activity)
        }

        return mBinding.root
    }

    override fun onSearchResult(symbols: List<Company>) {
        (mBinding.recyclerview.adapter as SearchAdapter).updateSymbols(symbols)
        (mBinding.recyclerview.adapter as SearchAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

#### SearchPresenter

```
@ActivityScope
class SearchPresenter @Inject constructor(private val mView: SearchContract.View) : SearchContract.Presenter {

    override fun search(filter: String) {
        mView.onSearchResult(listOf(Company(0, "APPL", "Apple Inc.")))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `onSearchResult` is being called before `onCreateView` so you could try to set `mBinding` to null in the initialization and remove `lateint` so you can check after that if `(mBinidng != null)` do what you want

Comment: Sure, the app won't crash now, but I'm not getting any functionality because `mBinding == null`